# Can not create Environment variable for AWS Lambda from CLI in MAC

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, command-line-interface

When I tried to create the Lambda function from Command line in MAC machine with environment variable using

```
--environment Variables="{dbRegion=us-east-1,sourceFileLocation=https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxx-123/config.xlsx,clientID=123}"
```

I got the following error

```
Unknown options: --environment, Variables="{dbRegion=us-east-1,sourceFileLocation=https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxx-123/config.xlsx,clientID=123}"
```

But the same command is working in Linux environments.

My current AWS CLI version is `aws-cli/1.11.13`

Comment: By MAC do you mean a machine with OS X?

Comment: yes, but when I update my aws-cli version to 1.14.x, its working fine

Comment: Make sure you upvote that answer then, and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AWS CLI version is old. I don't remember when `--environment` was added but I think it was early in the 1.14.x series.

The current version is 1.14.27.

Execute this command to update your system:

```
pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Mac problem

Some times came this issue.

Run the similar command using python it is working

```
import os
os.system("<aws cli create lambda command>")
```

And also working with terminal with only one argument.

```
manivannan@manivannan-whirldatascience:~/aws lambda create-function --function-name <your function name> --runtime java8 --role <your role arn> --handler <handler name> --zip-file fileb://<your zip file> --environment Variables={Key1=Value1} --timeout 30 --memory-size 512
```

I am working with aws cli version

```
aws-cli/1.11.178 Python/3.5.2 Linux/4.4.0-101-generic botocore/1.7.36
```

Try after some time it will work